How to visualize SIESTA relaxation output?
After a structural relaxation calculation using SIESTA, I want to visualize (like a GIF animation or a video) the ionic coordinate and/or cell structure relaxation. I can visualize a single structure from an input file using sisl such as:
path = pathlib.Path("/home/abdul/project/siesta/pure")
fdf = sisl.get_sile(path / "ZnS.fdf")
fdf.plot.geometry(axes="xyz")

However, what I am looking for is something like the following figure. This is generated using XCrySDen from a Quantum ESPRESSO ionic relaxation (the green arrows indicate forces but it's not necessary).

Relevant part of the input fdf file whose output I am trying to visualize:
MD.TypeOfRun      Broyden
MD.NumCGsteps     100
MD.MaxForceTol    0.0025 eV/Ang
WriteCoorStep     T
WriteCoorInitial  T
WriteForces       T


The SIESTA simulation should have produced a file with the .ANI extension. The name of the extension stands for "animation", but it really is nothing else than a normal xyz file containing the trajectory of the relaxation. You should be able to visualize it with any tool that can deal with xyz files containing trajectories. For example, I know that with VMD you can do:
vmd -xyz YourFile.ANI

and for any other program, I don't know how they work but you can rename the file to be .xyz and use it as usual.

Thanks a lot! I just checked that XCrySDen itself can visualize this .ANI file. It needs to be opened as an .xyz file - that's all.
